# angular ui-grid remove column hidden from export menu

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I don't want column hidden feature in ui-grid. So I used `enableHiding: false` in columns. But I can see columns in Grid export menu (show below)

[image: Gridexportmenu]

How can I remove `columns:` from grid menu ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, I need to disable on gridoption `gridMenuShowHideColumns: false`. Now all good.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/4971